# What is the correct way to bind data to a grid on a dropdownlist event?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendoUI dropdownlist that is populated with Catalog names, right now I have a grid being bound on the dropdown's select event. It seems to work fine, but I am wondering whether something like this should be done on the dropdownlist change event instead or maybe even on the close event. Here is a sample of a kendoUI dropDownList

```
    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data,
        filter: "startswith",
        select: onSelect,
        change: onChange,
        close: onClose,
        open: onOpen,
        filtering: onFiltering,
        dataBound:onDataBound
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, now, is to use the [`cascade` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-cascade). You may also use the `change` event if you're using older versions, but if you need to update the dropdown via code, you will have to make sure to take care of the grid also.

Your `cascade` event handler could look like this (provided you have set up the grid's dataSource to read it's data based on the dropdown's value):

```js
function catalogCascade() {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.fetch();
}
```